# Centering 45deg rotated div within another div

Tags: javascript, css, rotation

I have a main container of 930x180px. Within this container I have a div. Im rotating this div 45deg and looking to center it horizontal + vertical within my main container.

My approach for the centering has been to calculate width and height of my div to rotate and re-position top + left values.

My issue: is that the vertical centering seems to be off as you will be able to seen in the below codepen - the outer left bottom shows a good example of this.

How do I center my rotated div vertically correct to the main container?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYojVG

```
//main container
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
//div to rotate
    var lines = document.getElementById('lines');

var boxWidth = box.clientWidth;
var boxHeight = box.clientHeight;
var linesHeight = lines.clientHeight;
var linesWidth = lines.clientWidth;
var linesCenterPointCoordY = linesHeight / 2;
var linesCenterPointCoordX = (linesWidth-boxWidth) / 2;

//center div to box container
lines.style.top = "-" + linesCenterPointCoordY + "px";
lines.style.left = "-" + linesCenterPointCoordX + "px";

//change line rotation
TweenMax.set(lines, {
  rotation: '45',
  transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
})
```

Comment: Does the contianer div have a set height and width or is that just in the example?

Comment: The container will always have a fixed width + height. Only the div that im rotating that will have a dynamic height (defined it fixed with css in the example though)